# Can we have more than one context user for a single email service in salesforce?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I'm a newbie, and wanted to know if we can have more than one context user for a single email service? Based on any specific condition say, locale, the context user would be chosen. Please let me know the procedure of getting this done, if at all its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have more than one context user for one email service. Context user is not email service specific. Context user is specific to Email address. One email service can have multiple email address associated with it and each email address can have different Context User. Please see screenshot below for New email address page:

[image]

Also see this image which is showing that one email service has multiple email address and each email address has different Context user:

[image]